# Using Stripe Api with Swift IOS and Parse backend

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Hi I am working an a IOS application with Swift and ran into some problems interrogated the Stripe API to accepts payments. I have been able to generate  token from Stripe and using Swift but I am stuck on getting a tutorial or proper documentation on how I would use Parse backend to handle my charge. I am new to all this and don't know where to start. From what I have read the documentation I need to create some sort of Parse Cloud Code Function. Any ideas on where I should start to understanding all this or any help in general will be greatly appreciated!

P.S I am also looking to use Stripe Connect if you could lead me in a direction on where to find more on this

Answer (score 1):

You can find Parse's Stripe documentation at https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#cloud-code-modules-stripe. Unfortunately, their Stripe integration hasn't been updated in some time, so Connect isn't available as part of it. As such, I'd recommend just setting up your own backend for integrating with Stripe. We have an example backend written in Ruby at https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend, which makes this process pretty straightforward. From there, you'll be able to use the full [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api), including Connect.